# clock_gettime alternative in Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, time, clock

When compiling a program I wrote on Mac OS X after installing the necessary libraries through MacPorts, I get this error:

```
In function 'nanotime':
error: 'CLOCK_REALTIME' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
error: for each function it appears in.)
```

It appears that `clock_gettime` is not implemented in Mac OS X. Is there an alternative means of getting the **epoch time** in **nanoseconds**? Unfortunately `gettimeofday` is in **microseconds**.

Comment: My documentation says *"All implementations support the system-wide real-time clock, which is identified by CLOCK_REALTIME."* Did you `#include <time.h>`?

Comment: Yes, I have included `time.h`. Also, `man gettimeofday` works on OSX, while `man clock_gettime` does not.

Comment: Also try `cc -g \`pkg-config --cflags libcurl glib-2.0 libpcre libconfuse\` -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L -c getbooru-util.c`

Comment: That didn't help. `clock_gettime` is not implemented in Mac OS X.

Comment: On my system (Debian), to **link** I need the librt library.

Comment: I know. It's in my linker command line. I don't get up to the linking stage at all. Mac OS X doesn't have `clock_gettime`, while Linux does.

Comment: I wrote up a quick wrapper for this: https://gist.github.com/alfwatt/3588c5aa1f7a1ef7a3bb

Comment: Note that macOS Sierra 10.12 (September 2016, XCode 8) and later supports `clock_gettime()` directly — as noted in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39801564/15168) by [James Wald](http://stackoverflow.com/users/204480/james-wald).

Comment: In case people need yet another answer, take a look at the macports backwards compat implementation: https://github.com/macports/macports-legacy-support/blob/bce12afbf6e10e0216a87ba15c246b446fc810e1/src/time.c. And this is how apple implemented it https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1158.1.2/gen/clock_gettime.c.auto.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In effect, it seems not to be implemented for macOS before Sierra 10.12. You may want to look at this [blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20100517095152/http://www.wand.net.nz/%7Esmr26/wordpress/2009/01/19/monotonic-time-in-mac-os-x/comment-page-1/). The main idea is in the following code snippet:

```
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#define ORWL_NANO (+1.0E-9)
#define ORWL_GIGA UINT64_C(1000000000)

static double orwl_timebase = 0.0;
static uint64_t orwl_timestart = 0;

struct timespec orwl_gettime(void) {
  // be more careful in a multithreaded environement
  if (!orwl_timestart) {
    mach_timebase_info_data_t tb = { 0 };
    mach_timebase_info(&tb);
    orwl_timebase = tb.numer;
    orwl_timebase /= tb.denom;
    orwl_timestart = mach_absolute_time();
  }
  struct timespec t;
  double diff = (mach_absolute_time() - orwl_timestart) * orwl_timebase;
  t.tv_sec = diff * ORWL_NANO;
  t.tv_nsec = diff - (t.tv_sec * ORWL_GIGA);
  return t;
}
```

Comment: I don't want monotonic time though, I want the real time since the epoch, in nanoseconds.

Comment: Apparently MySQL (hmm Oracle) is trying to implement nanoseconds in Mac OS X ( @ http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44000 )

Comment: @Delan, I don't see why you would want that, this is useless precission for something counting in the order of magnitude of years. Ususally you need nanoseconds to time a function or so. Then it is sufficient to take the time before and after as it is done in that blog. But you could always simulate that by taking `gettimeofday` and `mach_absolute_time` at the beginning of your program and then add things up.

Comment: Never mix up monotonic and real time. Real time may jump as a NTP daemon corrects the system clock. They are two completely different things, really.

Comment: "blog entry" is now broken :(

Comment: Yes, and archive.org doesn't seem have an archive of this page.

Comment: Btw the way the code encapsulates a multiplication and a division in a variable by which it later multiplies lowers the precision of the net calculation unnecessarily. For integer math, it is best to do *all the multiplications first* before any divisions.

Comment: @JohnK: indeed, but the integer division adds a lot of unnecessary latency (11ns of the 32ns of the total calculation on my MBP). Is there a good way to avoid that without compromising the accuracy (too much)?

Comment: Use this link instead:
http://web.archive.org/web/20100517095152/http://www.wand.net.nz/~smr26/wordpress/2009/01/19/monotonic-time-in-mac-os-x/comment-page-1/

Comment: Is there something you need to do after upgrading to the correct OS version?

Comment: @carlos IIRC You need Xcode 8 or later after upgrading to Sierra.

Answer (score 131):

After hours of perusing different answers, blogs, and headers, I found a portable way to get the current time:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#ifdef __MACH__
#include <mach/clock.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#endif



struct timespec ts;

#ifdef __MACH__ // OS X does not have clock_gettime, use clock_get_time
clock_serv_t cclock;
mach_timespec_t mts;
host_get_clock_service(mach_host_self(), CALENDAR_CLOCK, &cclock);
clock_get_time(cclock, &mts);
mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), cclock);
ts.tv_sec = mts.tv_sec;
ts.tv_nsec = mts.tv_nsec;

#else
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
#endif
```

or check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/1087739

Hope this saves someone time. Cheers!

Comment: is host_get_clock_service expensive?  would it pay to cache it for the process ? is it reusable ? thread safe ?  Thanks - :)

Comment: also need includes: #ifdef \_\_MACH__
#include <mach/clock.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#endif

Comment: @NikolayVyahhi Yes! I have them in the gist. Though since you didn't find them, perhaps it's best to add them to the answer.

Comment: Has anybody perhaps timed the above `__MACH__` code? Using an independent microsecond-timer (well-tested) I get the impression, that two invocations of the above code cost ~25microseconds.

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to @peterk 's question. In my testing it seems like caching it doubles the performance, but do I need to cache it per thread, or can I create one and share it among all my threads?

Comment: Quick note, I have tested `mach_absolute_time()` takes 68 ns to run on 2015 MacBook Air

Answer (score 35):

None of the solutions above answers the question. Either they don't give you absolute Unix time, or their accuracy is 1 microsecond. The most popular solution by jbenet is slow (~6000ns) and does not count in nanoseconds even though its return suggests so. Below is a test for 2 solutions suggested by jbenet and Dmitri B, plus my take on this. You can run the code without changes.

The 3rd solution does count in nanoseconds and gives you absolute Unix time reasonably fast (~90ns). So if someone find it useful - please let us all know here :-). I will stick to the  one from Dmitri B (solution #1 in the code) - it fits my needs better.

I needed commercial quality alternative to clock_gettime() to make pthread_…timed.. calls, and found this discussion very helpful. Thanks guys.

```
/*
 Ratings of alternatives to clock_gettime() to use with pthread timed waits:
    Solution 1 "gettimeofday":
        Complexity      : simple
        Portability     : POSIX 1
        timespec        : easy to convert from timeval to timespec
        granularity     : 1000 ns,
        call            : 120 ns,
        Rating          : the best.

    Solution 2 "host_get_clock_service, clock_get_time":
        Complexity      : simple (error handling?)
        Portability     : Mac specific (is it always available?)
        timespec        : yes (struct timespec return)
        granularity     : 1000 ns (don't be fooled by timespec format)
        call time       : 6000 ns
        Rating          : the worst.

    Solution 3 "mach_absolute_time + gettimeofday once":
        Complexity      : simple..average (requires initialisation)
        Portability     : Mac specific. Always available
        timespec        : system clock can be converted to timespec without float-math
        granularity     : 1 ns.
        call time       : 90 ns unoptimised.
        Rating          : not bad, but do we really need nanoseconds timeout?

 References:
 - OS X is UNIX System 3 [U03] certified
    http://www.opengroup.org/homepage-items/c987.html

 - UNIX System 3 <--> POSIX 1 <--> IEEE Std 1003.1-1988
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX
    http://www.unix.org/version3/

 - gettimeofday() is mandatory on U03,
   clock_..() functions are optional on U03,
   clock_..() are part of POSIX Realtime extensions
    http://www.unix.org/version3/inttables.pdf

 - clock_gettime() is not available on MacMini OS X
    (Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Command Line Tools = Installed)

 - OS X recommends to use gettimeofday to calculate values for timespec
    https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/pthread_cond_timedwait.3.html

 - timeval holds microseconds, timespec - nanoseconds
    http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html

 - microtime() is used by kernel to implement gettimeofday()
    http://ftp.tw.freebsd.org/pub/branches/7.0-stable/src/sys/kern/kern_time.c

 - mach_absolute_time() is really fast
    http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-320.1.3/i386/mach/mach_absolute_time.c

 - Only 9 deciaml digits have meaning when int nanoseconds converted to double seconds
    Tutorial: Performance and Time post uses .12 precision for nanoseconds
    http://www.macresearch.org/tutorial_performance_and_time

 Example:
    Three ways to prepare absolute time 1500 milliseconds in the future to use with pthread timed functions.

 Output, N = 3, stock MacMini, OSX 10.7.5, 2.3GHz i5, 2GB 1333MHz DDR3:
    inittime.tv_sec = 1390659993
    inittime.tv_nsec = 361539000
    initclock = 76672695144136
    get_abs_future_time_0() : 1390659994.861599000
    get_abs_future_time_0() : 1390659994.861599000
    get_abs_future_time_0() : 1390659994.861599000
    get_abs_future_time_1() : 1390659994.861618000
    get_abs_future_time_1() : 1390659994.861634000
    get_abs_future_time_1() : 1390659994.861642000
    get_abs_future_time_2() : 1390659994.861643671
    get_abs_future_time_2() : 1390659994.861643877
    get_abs_future_time_2() : 1390659994.861643972
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>       /* gettimeofday */
#include <mach/mach_time.h> /* mach_absolute_time */
#include <mach/mach.h>      /* host_get_clock_service, mach_... */
#include <mach/clock.h>     /* clock_get_time */

#define BILLION 1000000000L
#define MILLION 1000000L

#define NORMALISE_TIMESPEC( ts, uint_milli )            \
    do {                                                \
        ts.tv_sec += uint_milli / 1000u;                \
        ts.tv_nsec += (uint_milli % 1000u) * MILLION;   \
        ts.tv_sec += ts.tv_nsec / BILLION;              \
        ts.tv_nsec = ts.tv_nsec % BILLION;              \
    } while (0)

static mach_timebase_info_data_t timebase = { 0, 0 }; /* numer = 0, denom = 0 */
static struct timespec           inittime = { 0, 0 }; /* nanoseconds since 1-Jan-1970 to init() */
static uint64_t                  initclock;           /* ticks since boot to init() */

void init()
{
    struct timeval  micro;      /* microseconds since 1 Jan 1970 */

    if (mach_timebase_info(&timebase) != 0)
        abort();                            /* very unlikely error */

    if (gettimeofday(&micro, NULL) != 0)
        abort();                            /* very unlikely error */

    initclock = mach_absolute_time();

    inittime.tv_sec = micro.tv_sec;
    inittime.tv_nsec = micro.tv_usec * 1000;
    printf("\tinittime.tv_sec = %ld\n", inittime.tv_sec);
    printf("\tinittime.tv_nsec = %ld\n", inittime.tv_nsec);
    printf("\tinitclock = %ld\n", (long)initclock);
}

/*
 * Get absolute future time for pthread timed calls
 *  Solution 1: microseconds granularity
 */
struct timespec get_abs_future_time_coarse(unsigned milli)
{
    struct timespec future;         /* ns since 1 Jan 1970 to 1500 ms in the future */
    struct timeval  micro = {0, 0}; /* 1 Jan 1970 */

    (void) gettimeofday(&micro, NULL);
    future.tv_sec = micro.tv_sec;
    future.tv_nsec = micro.tv_usec * 1000;
    NORMALISE_TIMESPEC( future, milli );
    return future;
}

/*
 * Solution 2: via clock service
 */
struct timespec get_abs_future_time_served(unsigned milli)
{
    struct timespec     future;
    clock_serv_t        cclock;
    mach_timespec_t     mts;

    host_get_clock_service(mach_host_self(), CALENDAR_CLOCK, &cclock);
    clock_get_time(cclock, &mts);
    mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), cclock);
    future.tv_sec = mts.tv_sec;
    future.tv_nsec = mts.tv_nsec;
    NORMALISE_TIMESPEC( future, milli );
    return future;
}

/*
 * Solution 3: nanosecond granularity
 */
struct timespec get_abs_future_time_fine(unsigned milli)
{
    struct timespec future;     /* ns since 1 Jan 1970 to 1500 ms in future */
    uint64_t        clock;      /* ticks since init */
    uint64_t        nano;       /* nanoseconds since init */

    clock = mach_absolute_time() - initclock;
    nano = clock * (uint64_t)timebase.numer / (uint64_t)timebase.denom;
    future = inittime;
    future.tv_sec += nano / BILLION;
    future.tv_nsec += nano % BILLION;
    NORMALISE_TIMESPEC( future, milli );
    return future;
}

#define N 3

int main()
{
    int                 i, j;
    struct timespec     time[3][N];
    struct timespec   (*get_abs_future_time[])(unsigned milli) =
    {
        &get_abs_future_time_coarse,
        &get_abs_future_time_served,
        &get_abs_future_time_fine
    };

    init();
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            time[j][i] = get_abs_future_time[j](1500);  /* now() + 1500 ms */

    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            printf("get_abs_future_time_%d() : %10ld.%09ld\n",
                   j, time[j][i].tv_sec, time[j][i].tv_nsec);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just as an FYI. On my system a call to `mach_absolute_time()` plus the multiplication by `info.numer / info.denom` takes more or less 33ns per call: benchmark: https://gist.github.com/aktau/9f52f812200d8d69a5d1 libuv issue: https://github.com/joyent/libuv/pull/1325

Answer (score 29):

```
#if defined(__MACH__) && !defined(CLOCK_REALTIME)
#include <sys/time.h>
#define CLOCK_REALTIME 0
// clock_gettime is not implemented on older versions of OS X (< 10.12).
// If implemented, CLOCK_REALTIME will have already been defined.
int clock_gettime(int /*clk_id*/, struct timespec* t) {
    struct timeval now;
    int rv = gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    if (rv) return rv;
    t->tv_sec  = now.tv_sec;
    t->tv_nsec = now.tv_usec * 1000;
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Comment: If you use CLOCK_REALTIME or CLOCK_MONOTONIC, you should also define these:
    #define CLOCK_REALTIME 0
    #define CLOCK_MONOTONIC 0

Comment: Because a) the precision is 1000x lower (although that is not so bad, as the granularity of time really returned by `clock_gettime` will rarely (never) be one nanosecond), and b) the time returned by `gettimeofday` is different and non-monotonic. It may jump wildly (e.g. when daylight saving time takes place), or it may even run at slightly slower / faster (!) pace, after time server synchronization took place where the time service may want to avoid small abrupt changes to time.

Comment: Unfortunately, the time of day is not a monotonic clock.  (The monotonic clock exists specifically to avoid all the issues associated with a time-of-day clock, including administrators or NTP changing the time, leap seconds, time zones, etc.)

Answer (score 22):

Everything you need is described in [Technical Q&A QA1398: Technical Q&A QA1398: Mach Absolute Time Units](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/), basically the function you want is `mach_absolute_time`.

Here's a slightly earlier version of the sample code from that page that does everything using Mach calls (the current version uses `AbsoluteToNanoseconds` from CoreServices).  In current OS X (i.e., on Snow Leopard on x86_64) the absolute time values are actually in nanoseconds and so don't actually require any conversion at all.  So, if you're good and writing portable code, you'll convert, but if you're just doing something quick and dirty for yourself, you needn't bother.

FWIW, `mach_absolute_time` is *really* fast.

```
uint64_t GetPIDTimeInNanoseconds(void)
{
    uint64_t        start;
    uint64_t        end;
    uint64_t        elapsed;
    uint64_t        elapsedNano;
    static mach_timebase_info_data_t    sTimebaseInfo;

    // Start the clock.

    start = mach_absolute_time();

    // Call getpid. This will produce inaccurate results because 
    // we're only making a single system call. For more accurate 
    // results you should call getpid multiple times and average 
    // the results.

    (void) getpid();

    // Stop the clock.

    end = mach_absolute_time();

    // Calculate the duration.

    elapsed = end - start;

    // Convert to nanoseconds.

    // If this is the first time we've run, get the timebase.
    // We can use denom == 0 to indicate that sTimebaseInfo is 
    // uninitialised because it makes no sense to have a zero 
    // denominator is a fraction.

    if ( sTimebaseInfo.denom == 0 ) {
        (void) mach_timebase_info(&sTimebaseInfo);
    }

    // Do the maths. We hope that the multiplication doesn't 
    // overflow; the price you pay for working in fixed point.

    elapsedNano = elapsed * sTimebaseInfo.numer / sTimebaseInfo.denom;

    printf("multiplier %u / %u\n", sTimebaseInfo.numer, sTimebaseInfo.denom);
    return elapsedNano;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Note that macOS Sierra 10.12 now supports clock_gettime():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    struct timespec res;
    struct timespec time;

    clock_getres(CLOCK_REALTIME, &res);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);

    printf("CLOCK_REALTIME: res.tv_sec=%lu res.tv_nsec=%lu\n", res.tv_sec, res.tv_nsec);
    printf("CLOCK_REALTIME: time.tv_sec=%lu time.tv_nsec=%lu\n", time.tv_sec, time.tv_nsec);
}
```

It does provide nanoseconds; however, the resolution is 1000, so it is (in)effectively limited to microseconds:

```
CLOCK_REALTIME: res.tv_sec=0 res.tv_nsec=1000
CLOCK_REALTIME: time.tv_sec=1475279260 time.tv_nsec=525627000
```

You will need XCode 8 or later to be able to use this feature.  Code compiled to use this feature will not run on versions of Mac OS X (10.11 or earlier).

Comment: I'm on macOS 10.12 but unable to compile the above; I get `Use of undeclared identifier 'CLOCK_REALTIME'`

Comment: Strange, that should be available with: #include <time.h>. Try "xcode-select --install" to update the command line developer tools.

Comment: yeah my Xcode is v7. Its painful for me to download the 4GB Xcode8; I am paranoid about the data used by `xcode-slect --install`!

Comment: @JamesWald: I've put a comment under the question pointing to your answer.  An upvote on the comment would improve its visibility (several upvotes would be even better).

Comment: A word of caution: if you build using XCode 8 (or later) but target versions of OSX older than 10.12 you will find the `clock_gettime` symbol at compile time but upon running the binary on the 10.11 or below you will get "dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime" because the compiler generated a weak symbol.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for your posts

I think you can add the following lines

```
#ifdef __MACH__
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#define CLOCK_REALTIME 0
#define CLOCK_MONOTONIC 0
int clock_gettime(int clk_id, struct timespec *t){
    mach_timebase_info_data_t timebase;
    mach_timebase_info(&timebase);
    uint64_t time;
    time = mach_absolute_time();
    double nseconds = ((double)time * (double)timebase.numer)/((double)timebase.denom);
    double seconds = ((double)time * (double)timebase.numer)/((double)timebase.denom * 1e9);
    t->tv_sec = seconds;
    t->tv_nsec = nseconds;
    return 0;
}
#else
#include <time.h>
#endif
```

Let me know what you get for latency and granularity

Comment: It would be better if you cached the `mach_timebase_info` call (perhaps with a static variable to keep it tidy). `mach_timebase_info()` is a syscall and takes ~180ns on my machine. As opposed to the ~22ns for `mach_absolute_time()`, which is basically just sampling `rdtsc`.

Comment: Interestingly from about 10.12 onwards it's no longer a direct syscall and Apple already implements caching at the libc layer https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3789.41.3/libsyscall/wrappers/mach_timebase_info.c.auto.html. This is not the case for older OS though.

Answer (score 4):

Maristic has the best answer here to date. Let me simplify and add a remark. `#include` and `Init()`:

```
#include <mach/mach_time.h>

double conversion_factor;

void Init() {
  mach_timebase_info_data_t timebase;
  mach_timebase_info(&timebase);
  conversion_factor = (double)timebase.numer / (double)timebase.denom;
}
```

Use as:

```
  uint64_t t1, t2;

  Init();

  t1 = mach_absolute_time();
  /* profiled code here */
  t2 = mach_absolute_time();

  double duration_ns = (double)(t2 - t1) * conversion_factor;
```

Such timer has latency of `65ns +/- 2ns` (2GHz CPU). Use this if you need "time evolution" of single execution. Otherwise loop your code `10000` times and profile even with `gettimeofday()`, which is portable (POSIX), and has the latency of `100ns +/- 0.5ns` (though only `1us` granularity).

Comment: Any idea of the impact of the conversion to double on the precision? AFAIK a double has only 53-bits of precision and `mach_absolute_time` can return anything in a 64-bit range. Just curious.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the version with clock_get_time, and did cache the host_get_clock_service call.  It's way slower than gettimeofday, it takes several microseconds per invocation. And, what's worse, the return value has steps of 1000, i.e. it's still microsecond granularity.

I'd advice to use gettimeofday, and multiply tv_usec by 1000.

Comment: The time returned by `gettimeofday` is potentially non-monotonic. It may jump wildly (e.g. when daylight saving time takes place), or it may even run at slightly slower / faster (!) pace, after time server synchronization took place where the time service may want to avoid small abrupt changes to time.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the open source [mach_absolute_time.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-320/i386/mach/mach_absolute_time.c) we can see that the line `extern mach_port_t clock_port;` tells us there's a mach port already initialized for monotonic time. This clock port can be accessed directly without having to resort to calling `mach_absolute_time` then converting **back** to a `struct timespec`. Bypassing a call to `mach_absolute_time` should improve performance.

I created a small [Github repo (PosixMachTiming)](https://github.com/ChisholmKyle/PosixMachTiming) with the code based on the extern `clock_port` and a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31688254/3183836). [PosixMachTiming](https://github.com/ChisholmKyle/PosixMachTiming) emulates `clock_gettime` for `CLOCK_REALTIME` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`. It also emulates the function `clock_nanosleep` for absolute monotonic time. Please give it a try and see how the performance compares. Maybe you might want to create comparative tests or emulate other POSIX clocks/functions?

Answer (score 1):

As of at least as far back as Mountain Lion, `mach_absolute_time()` returns *nanoseconds* and not absolute time (which was the number of bus cycles).

The following code on my MacBook Pro (2 GHz Core i7) showed that the time to call `mach_absolute_time()` averaged 39 ns over 10 runs (min 35, max 45), which is basically the time between the return of the two calls to mach_absolute_time(), about 1 invocation:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   uint64_t now, then;
   uint64_t abs;

   then = mach_absolute_time(); // return nanoseconds
   now = mach_absolute_time();
   abs = now - then;

   cout << "nanoseconds = " << abs << endl;
}
```

Comment: IIRC, all the Intel hardware uses nanoseconds, and all of the PowerPC hardware used bus cycles regardless of OS version, but the G5 might have used nanoseconds—I forget.

Answer (score 1):

```
void clock_get_uptime(uint64_t *result);

void clock_get_system_microtime(            uint32_t *secs,
                                            uint32_t *microsecs);

void clock_get_system_nanotime(             uint32_t *secs,
                                            uint32_t *nanosecs);
void clock_get_calendar_microtime(          uint32_t *secs,
                                            uint32_t *microsecs);

void clock_get_calendar_nanotime(           uint32_t *secs,
                                            uint32_t *nanosecs);
```

For MacOS you can find a good information on their developers page
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/services/services.html

Answer (score 0):

I found another portable solution.

Declare in some header file (or even in your source one):

```
/* If compiled on DARWIN/Apple platforms. */
#ifdef DARWIN
#define    CLOCK_REALTIME    0x2d4e1588
#define    CLOCK_MONOTONIC   0x0
#endif /* DARWIN */
```

And the add the function implementation:

```
#ifdef DARWIN

/*
 * Bellow we provide an alternative for clock_gettime,
 * which is not implemented in Mac OS X.
 */
static inline int clock_gettime(int clock_id, struct timespec *ts)
{
    struct timeval tv;

    if (clock_id != CLOCK_REALTIME) 
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
    if (gettimeofday(&tv, NULL) < 0) 
    {
        return -1;
    }
    ts->tv_sec = tv.tv_sec;
    ts->tv_nsec = tv.tv_usec * 1000;
    return 0;
}

#endif /* DARWIN */
```

Don't forget to include `<time.h>`.