# Current microsecond time in C?

Tags: c, unix, time

How can I print current microseconds time in C on Unix platform?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a timestamp in C in microseconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833094/get-a-timestamp-in-c-in-microseconds) Now possible with `timespec_get` from C11: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36095514/895245

Answer (score 7):

In Linux and BSDs, you can use the `gettimeofday()` function. This populates a `timeval` struct which has a field for seconds since the epoch and a field for microseconds. This function is deprecated. The higher resolution [clock_gettime()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) is the favored replacement, however Mac OS X does not implement it. I'm not sure if Windows implements either of these.

Comment: For higher resolution than microseconds on OS X, try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167269/clock-gettime-alternative-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 5):

There is no portable (multiplatform) way to get that number. On Linux (or other POSIX systems) for example there is the call [gettimeofday](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) that provides exactly that precision (accuracy however will depend if that timing is available and implemented on the specific hardware).

Comment: Strictly speaking I think it provides that *precision*, not necessarily that accuracy. But AFAIK it's the best you're going to get for wall clock time.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Thanx. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard doesn't provide a standard means for that. However the `clock()` function returns time in CLOCK's. there are `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` CLOCK's in a second. On my machine and implementation, CLOCKS_PER_SEC is defined as 1000. Both `clock` and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` are defined in `<time.h>`. Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux, I would check out this site: http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/functions/time.html
Particularly the 'gettimeofday' function. Which you can pass a structure, and get the time of day in microseconds.