# how to print time in micro seconds using ctime() function?

Tags: c++, linux

HI how to print time in macro second also with the use of following function in c++, I am using,

```
time_t rawtime;
time(&rawtime);
std::cout<<"Cuuent TIme is ::  "<< ctime(&rawtime)<< std::endl;
```

Above code will give me only hours, minutes and second. I also need the micro seconds. 
Any suggestion how to get time with micro seconds also?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a timestamp in C in microseconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833094/get-a-timestamp-in-c-in-microseconds)

Comment: There are so many duplicates - the one above is an example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used following code to get time in H,M,S,mS:

```
 char timeBuf  [256]; 
 struct timeval tv;
 struct timezone tz;
 struct tm *tm;
 gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
 tm=localtime(&tv.tv_sec);
 sprintf (timeBuf, "%02d:%02d:%02d:%03ld",tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec, (tv.tv_usec/1000) );
```

Answer (score 1):

BSalunke, look at this piece of code. Includes the uSeconds and the time_t structure you were using.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
        struct timeval timeValue;
        long uSeconds;

        if ( gettimeofday( &timeValue, NULL ) == 0 )
        {
                // This is what you have:
                time_t time = timeValue.tv_sec;
                // This is what you are looking for:
                printf( "Current milliseconds: %ld\n", timeValue.tv_usec );
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        else
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. `gettimeofday()`
2. `clock(...)`

Comment: but can i get the time with hours, minits, second and also microseconds? with the use of above my code?

Comment: @BSalunke, I provided the methods you need to look at, and duplicate questions where this material is covered, you need to read the documentation - and yes it's possible.