# Get the current time, in milliseconds, in C?

Tags: c

What is the equivalence of the Java's `System.currentTimeMillis()` in C?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303751/current-microsecond-time-in-c. Good answers there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to measure time in milliseconds using ANSI C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361363/how-to-measure-time-in-milliseconds-using-ansi-c)

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <sys/time.h>
/**
* @brief provide same output with the native function in java called
* currentTimeMillis().
*/
int64_t currentTimeMillis() {
  struct timeval time;
  gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
  int64_t s1 = (int64_t)(time.tv_sec) * 1000;
  int64_t s2 = (time.tv_usec / 1000);
  return s1 + s2;
}
```

I write this function just like `System.currentTimeMillis()` in Java, and they have the same output.

Answer (score 3):

Check `time.h`, perhaps something like the `gettimeofday()` function.

You can do something like

```
struct timeval now;
gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
```

Then you can extract time by getting values from `now.tv_sec` and `now.tv_usec`.

Comment: And what units are `now.tv_sec` and `now.tv_usec`?

Comment: Seconds and Microseconds.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux and other Unix-like systems, you should use [clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime). If this is not available (e.g. Linux 2.4), you can fall back to [gettimeofday()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday). The latter has the drawback of being affected by clock adjustments.

On Windows, you can use [QueryPerformanceCounter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[This code](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/source/browse/trunk/system/BTime.h) of mine abstracts all of the above into a simple interface that returns the number of milliseconds as an int64_t. Note that the millisecond values returned are intended only for relative use (e.g. timeouts), and are not relative to any particular time.

Comment: `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is not quite equivalent to the java function, as the java function is also affected by wallclock adjustments. It's the right choice for interval timers, of course, but if the OP wants a wallclock time it's not going to help.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/51247-current-system-time-milliseconds.html

It says that the time() function is accurate to seconds, and deeper accuracy requires other libraries...

Answer (score 0):

There's the [time()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/) function, but it returns seconds, not milliseconds.  If you need greater precision, you can use platform-specific functions like Windows' [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or *nix's [gettimeofday()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday).

If you don't actually care about the date and time but just want to time the interval between two events, like this:

```
long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
// ... do something that takes a while ...
long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedMS = time2 - time1;
```

then the C equivalent is [clock()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/).  On Windows, it's more common to use [GetTickCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this purpose.