# How to save date time stamp within 4 bytes

Tags: c, embedded

I want to log my embedded system start time and date in to memory.
here I want to know that there is any standard to save datetime stamp within 4 bytes.
The system is worked on arm7 with free rtos. The board contains RTC
Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Do your system have any kind of operating system? Does it have any functionality to get the current time (like the [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) function)? What is the size of the data type returned by that function? Is it four bytes or less? Then you have your solution.

Comment: If you *don't* have any operating system, but run on the "bare metal", then you could read the real-time clock directly and format the date and time in just any way you please.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg And even if one has an operating system, one could still get RTC time.

Comment: The system is worked on arm7 with free rtos. The board contains RTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structures below show three methods of storing time and date within 4 bytes (or 32 bits).

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct TIMESTAMP_32_A_S
   {
   uint8_t   seconds    : 6; // 0-60 (0-63 max)
   uint8_t   minutes    : 6; // 0-60 (0-63 max)
   uint8_t   hours24    : 5; // 0-23 (0-31 max)
   uint8_t   dayOfMonth : 5; // 1-31 (0-31 max)
   uint8_t   month      : 4; // 1-12 (0-15 max)
   uint8_t   year       : 6; // Epoch start: 2014, Range: 2014 thru 2077
   } TIMESTAMP_32_A_T;                                                  
#pragma pack()
```

The structure above assumes that the granularity of `seconds` is important to the application.  It also assumes that the application will not be executed prior to the `year` 2014, or after the `year` 2077 (at which time, `year` will roll back to 2014).

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct TIMESTAMP_32_B_S
   {
   uint8_t   minutes    : 6; // 0-60 (0-63 max)
   uint8_t   hours24    : 5; // 0-23 (0-31 max)
   uint8_t   dayOfMonth : 5; // 1-31 (0-31 max)
   uint8_t   month      : 4; // 1-12 (0-15 max)
   uint16_t  year       : 12; // Epoch start: 2014, Range: 2014 thru 4061
   } TIMESTAMP_32_B_T;
#pragma pack()
```

The structure above assumes that `seconds` are irrelevant to the application. It also assumes that the application will not be executed prior to the `year` 2014, or after the `year` 4061 (at which time, `year` will roll back to 2014).

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct TIMESTAMP_32_C_S
   {
   uint8_t   secondsBy2 : 5; // 0-30 (0-31 max)
   uint8_t   minutes    : 6; // 0-60 (0-63 max)
   uint8_t   hours24    : 5; // 0-23 (0-31 max)
   uint8_t   dayOfMonth : 5; // 1-31 (0-31 max)
   uint8_t   month      : 4; // 1-12 (0-15 max)
   uint8_t   year       : 7; // Epoch start: 2014, Range: 2014 thru 2141
   } TIMESTAMP_32_C_T;
#pragma pack()
```

The structure above assumes that a `seconds` granularity of 2-second intervals are is sufficient to the application. It also assumes that the application will not be executed prior to the `year` 2014, or after the `year` 2141 (at which time, `year` will roll back to 2014). MSDOS used a similar structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the seconds since specific time, like stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10098567/435605).

For example, measuring seconds since 1970 will provide range until year 2038.

If you measure secs since 2021, it will provide you range for up to 2089.