# What is the best way to save epoch time in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, biginteger, epoch

I'm using the epoch time format to save date. My problem is Java `Long` is enough to handle this or should I consider Java `BigInteger` to handle the epoch time?

Comment: `long` will be good enough.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean UNIX epoch, Java long is more then enough. [UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is number of seconds since January 1, 1970 and is stored (in UNIX) as a 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a long is sufficient.  But in terms of the *best* way, consider using native types.

In Java <= 7, [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is designed for this purpose.  It has *millisecond* precision.

In Java >= 8, [`java.time.Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is designed for this purpose.  It has *nanosecond* precision.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library commonly used in place of java.util.Date also tracks time by [milliseconds](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).

Answer (score 2):

If by [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), you mean **seconds** since 1970, long will of course do the job, as it can represent millis as well up until end of time ;-)

My point is that you can might integer instead. it will represent time in secs since 1970 up to year **2038**.

If you don't need to represent time before now, consider using a special format like stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25155400/435605). This will help you represent a wider future range.

Another option for representing time only after now, is starting the measure since 2021, by subtracting the seconds: `nowSecs - 2021Secs`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can get the milliseconds since the UNIX Epoch with [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) which returns a long, so there's no reason to consider something else.