# System.currentTimeMillis() for C# and objective c

Tags: c#, objective-c, milliseconds

I tried to convert it to objective c code using:

```
double timeSince1970 = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

but had no luck
Please help !!

Comment: Your Objective-C code is fine. You just need to multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

in c # used

```
Environment.TickCount
```

and in c look at this answer

[Get the current time, in milliseconds, in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098441/get-the-current-time-in-milliseconds-in-c)