# How can I get a(n extremely precise) time stamp?

Tags: unix, time

How can I get (some kind of a extremely precise) time stamp?

My application needs to get and store (accurate) server time, including hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

How can I get this (extremely precise) time stamp?

Answer (score 1):

Use clock_gettime(3). For more info look [here](http://tdistler.com/2010/06/27/high-performance-timing-on-linux-windows).

Comment: Looks like that doesn't exist on OSX (bah!) but there's a relatively easy reimplementation in terms of Mach calls. The answers to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167269/clock-gettime-alternative-in-mac-os-x) seem reasonably extensive.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not seem to need nanosecond precision, the correct and portable way of doing this is *not* to play with `mach_absolute_time()`, but by using `gettimeofday()`:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
```

…

```
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
```

…

You can then access the seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC in `tv.tv_sec` and the microseconds in `tv.tv_usec`.