# clock_getres alternative in Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos

I need to find the clock resolution(precision) but `clock_getres()` is not implemented in MacOS X.

Is there an alternative function in C to get the clock resolution?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167269/clock-gettime-alternative-in-mac-os-x

Comment: Thanks, used this clock_get_attributes(clk_system, CLOCK_GET_TIME_RES,
                              (clock_attr_t)attribute, &count);