# Repeating function invoking like NSTimer in C

Tags: c, macos, nstimer, core-foundation

I find myself in need for a repeating block of code I can execute.  If I were in an object I could simply pass self to the NSTimer scheduling.  I am in a pure C project at the moment and I don't see any obvious NSTimer analogs.  Is there a correct way to approach this?

Comment: C has no timers in the standard. You need to use platform-specific APIs.

Comment: in that case is there a suitable alternative in Core Foundation?

Comment: No idea, but you probably should use an appropriate tag in your question.

Comment: What about GCD timer sources? (dispatch_* family)

Comment: Grand Central Dispatch.  See [this example](https://gist.github.com/maicki/7622108).

Answer (score 1):

### If you really want the CF way of doing this:

`CFRunLoopTimer` is the CoreFoundation counter-part you're probably looking for.

You'll need to construct a separate `CFRunLoop` on a different thread if you want the timer to fire an asynchronous job. Otherwise, you can use use the main application thread by calling `CFRunLoopGetCurrent()` and set that to be the "parent loop" (called a "mode") that responds to the timer's events.

---

#### Here's what you do:

1. Initialize a [`CFRunLoopTimerContext`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/cfrunlooptimercontext?language=objc) struct (on the stack is fine)
2. Calculate the next time at which the run loop fires using type `CFAbsoluteTime` and `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` plus some `CFTimeInterval` (can be a `double` aka `CGFloat`)
3. Create the run loop timer with [`CFRunLoopTimerCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1666612-cfrunlooptimer?language=objc), passing in the next fire time and the callback function pointer
4. Add the run loop timer to either a runloop on a separate thread or the main thread of the executable (see above)

Comment: ... but using [Grand Central Dispatch](https://gist.github.com/maicki/7622108) as @trojanfoe recommended above will likely yield a more optimised binary when compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much of anything about the foundation framework but you can hack together a timer using the [mach/POSIX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Mach/Mach.html) APIs which allow you to tap into kernel services and processes for your C application.

Using a combination of `mach_absolute_time()` and `nanosleep()` system calls may allow you to emulate a timer. It's a bit nasty if you've never done any systems programming on a *NIX like platform.

On Linux, it's much easier to implement a POSIX timer or make use of `clock_gettime()` and `clock_nanosleep` (POSIX functions) which are not available on the mac.

There's lots of info on Linux/Unix systems programming in C but not so much on a mac, so I'd recommend having a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167269/clock-gettime-alternative-in-mac-os-x).

Also, I made my own little emulation of `clock_gettime()` and `clock_nanosleep` for the mac (shameless plug) [Find it here](https://github.com/ChisholmKyle/PosixMachTiming)